# Setting up SANED with sane-test

Tags: networking, virtualbox, services, scanner, sane

I'm trying to setup a network service for running saned (running the sane-test backend) on Ubuntu 12.10, running it on a virtualbox.

I followed the directions found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ScanningHowTo) and I got to the point where if I use a front-end like xsane, or use the command `scanimage -d test` i get the desired behaviour. (i get the test image).

But when i try to use the network demon to access the backend (from the localhost) I get Failed to connect.

I used `telnet` on `127.0.0.1 6566` and i got the following error:

```
saned: symbol lookup error: 
saned: undefined symbol: sanei_w_init
```

I'm a linux newbie, so I could be making some stupid mistake. Any ideas on how to fix this?

[update] After posting this question i logged out, logged back in and it worked. After a few days I tried again and it gave the same error as before. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The problem lay in having installed SANE, not knowing that it was already installed in the machine. It was the duplicate installation that was creating the mess.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is there is that you have files that Ubuntu has installed. You can easily resolve this problem however it may cause problems later on with package management.

Per the README.txt

> Please check that there aren't any older versions of SANE installed on your
>   system. Especially if SANE libraries are installed in a different prefix
>   directory (e.g. /usr/lib/) this may cause problems with external
>   frontends. Please remove these libraries (libsane.*, sane/libsane-*) by using
>   your packet manager or manually before installing this version of SANE.

Simply nuke `/usr/lib/sane`.

```
rm -rf /usr/lib/sane/*
```

Alternatively, things that use libsane should search in /usr/local/lib first. That's where SANE installs to.

Answer (score 0):

Ola Pessoal, aqui no GNU/Linux KDu-2.0-Final eu resolvi depois de procurar instalar de varias formas , até que finalmente o Scanner esta plenamente funcional, aproveitei e crie para vocês um Script instalador, de permissões ao script e clique e esta pronto para funcionar no seu Linux base Debian / ubuntu 12.04 /12.10 em minutos o seu scanner .

http://indexdata.com.br/Linux/Drivers/Scanner/HP/hp2400c/hp2400c-hpG2410install

atenciosamente...

SuporteTecnicoID